# React Redux state conditional bug and useEffect dependency bugs out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that gets a detail of a single post via params.id the component works when I remove all the dependencies on the  useEffect but doesnt input the value from the redux state to the component states, when I put the dependencies back it gives me an  error of title is undefined, but the redux action returns successfully as I have the data, I think the component loads first before receiving the redux action payload?

```
const UpdatePost = ({ match, history }) => {
  const postId = match.params.id;

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const postDetails = useSelector(state => state.postDetails);
  const { loading, error, post } = postDetails;

  const postUpdate = useSelector(state => state.postUpdate);
  const {
    loading: loadingUpdate,
    error: errorUpdate,
    success: successUpdate,
  } = postUpdate;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (successUpdate) {
      dispatch({ type: POST_UPDATE_RESET });
      dispatch({ type: POST_DETAILS_RESET });
      history.push('/edit/post');
    } else {
      console.log(post, postId);
      if (!post.title || post._id !== postId) {
        dispatch(listPostDetails(postId));
      } else {
        setTitle(post.title);
        setDescription(post.description);
        setImage(post.image);
      }
    }
  }, [post, history, dispatch, postId, successUpdate]);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      updatePost({
        _id: postId,
        title,
        description,
        image,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <MotionBox
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1 }}
      bgColor={'#eaeaea'}
      my="1rem"
      border="2px"
      borderColor="#eaeaea"
      borderRadius="25px"
      p={{ base: '2rem 2rem' }}
    >
      <Heading color={'#435943'} size="lg" pb={'1.5rem'}>
        Edit User
      </Heading>
      {loadingUpdate && <Loader />}
      {errorUpdate && <Message status="error">{errorUpdate}</Message>}
      {loading && loadingUpdate ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message status="error">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <FormControl pb={'1rem'}>
            <FormLabel size="md">Edit Post Title</FormLabel>
            <Input
              borderColor="#d4d6d5"
              placeholder="Edit Post Title"
              value={title}
              onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl pb={'1rem'}>
            <FormLabel size="md">Edit Post Description</FormLabel>
            <Textarea
              size="md"
              value={description}
              onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.checked)}
              placeholder="Edit Post Descrription"
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl pb={'1rem'}>
            <FormLabel size="md">Edit Post Photo</FormLabel>
            <Input
              size="md"
              placeholder="Edit Post Photo"
              value={image}
              onChange={e => setImage(e.target.checked)}
            />
          </FormControl>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            my={'2rem'}
            fontSize={'md'}
            fontWeight={600}
            color="white"
            bg={'green.800'}
            _hover={{
              background: 'green.600',
            }}
            _focus={{
              outline: 'none',
              border: 'none',
            }}
          >
            Update
          </Button>
        </form>
      )}
    </MotionBox>
  );
};
```

Comment: It loads correctly but the component seems to be loading first before receiving and adding.

Comment: react uses referencial equality, so your effect is not run if you update the value in your object. you should use `useEffect(..., [post.id, ...])`

Comment: What is `post`? There's no such variable. Did you mean `postDetails`?

Comment: It is destructured here `const { loading, error, post } = postDetails;` the data now displays on the inputs for a ssecond then  throws me the error  `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` for some reason.